# SQL UNION. Results appearing in the wrong columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have this long SQL UNION Query. So, i have two tables with the same column names but potentially different data. I am writing this query to check the columns on both tables for differences and displaying the difference. My issue being that the differences are coming back under the wrong columns. All the results are coming back under the heading of the columns in the first SELECT statement. I want the columns that are different to come back under the right column names to make it clear where the differences are. Here is my code and a picture of the outputed result. I have put comments beside which SELECT statements return differences.

```
SELECT DISTINCT --All Differences are coming under these headings
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'Star Gross',
CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'PR Gross',
CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'Gross Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'Star NetPay',
CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'PR NetPay',
CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'NetPay Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.StudentLoanDeductions AS FLOAT) AS 'Star StudentLoanDeductions',
CAST(pr.StudentLoanDeductions AS FLOAT) AS 'PR StudentLoanDeductions',
CAST(s.StudentLoanDeductions AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.StudentLoanDeductions AS FLOAT) AS 'StudentLoanDeductions Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.StudentLoanDeductions AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.StudentLoanDeductions AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT --Different
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Total AS FLOAT) AS 'Star Total',
CAST(pr.Total AS FLOAT) AS 'PR Total',
CAST(s.Total AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Total AS FLOAT) AS 'Total Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Total AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Total AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT --Different
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Earnings_To_LEL AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EarningsToLEL',
CAST(pr.Earnings_To_LEL AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EarningsToLEL',
CAST(s.Earnings_To_LEL AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Earnings_To_LEL AS FLOAT) AS 'EarningsToLEL Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Earnings_To_LEL AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Earnings_To_LEL AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Earnings_To_SET AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EarningsToSET',
CAST(pr.Earnings_To_SET AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EarningsToSET',
CAST(s.Earnings_To_SET AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Earnings_To_SET AS FLOAT) AS 'EarningsToSET Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Earnings_To_SET AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Earnings_To_SET AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT --Different
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Earnings_To_PET AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EarningsToPET',
CAST(pr.Earnings_To_PET AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EarningsToPET',
CAST(s.Earnings_To_PET AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Earnings_To_PET AS FLOAT) AS 'EarningsToPET Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Earnings_To_PET AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Earnings_To_PET AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT --Different
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Earnings_To_UST AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EarningsToUST',
CAST(pr.Earnings_To_UST AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EarningsToUST',
CAST(s.Earnings_To_UST AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Earnings_To_UST AS FLOAT) AS 'EarningsToUST Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Earnings_To_UST AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Earnings_To_UST AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Earnings_To_AUST AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EarningsToAUST',
CAST(pr.Earnings_To_AUST AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EarningsToAUST',
CAST(s.Earnings_To_AUST AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Earnings_To_AUST AS FLOAT) AS 'EarningsToAUST Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Earnings_To_AUST AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Earnings_To_AUST AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Earnings_To_UEL AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EarningsToUEL',
CAST(pr.Earnings_To_UEL AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EarningsToUEL',
CAST(s.Earnings_To_UEL AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Earnings_To_UEL AS FLOAT) AS 'EarningsToUEL Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Earnings_To_UEL AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Earnings_To_UEL AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Earnings_Above_UEL AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EarningsAboveUEL',
CAST(pr.Earnings_Above_UEL AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EarningsAboveUEL',
CAST(s.Earnings_Above_UEL AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Earnings_Above_UEL AS FLOAT) AS 'EarningsAboveUEL Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Earnings_Above_UEL AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Earnings_Above_UEL AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT --Different
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Ee_Contributions_Pt1 AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EeContributionsPT1',
CAST(pr.Ee_Contributions_Pt1 AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EeContributionsPT1',
CAST(s.Ee_Contributions_Pt1 AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Ee_Contributions_Pt1 AS FLOAT) AS 'EeContributionsPT1 Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Ee_Contributions_Pt1 AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Ee_Contributions_Pt1 AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Ee_Contributions_Pt2 AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EeContributionsPT2',
CAST(pr.Ee_Contributions_Pt2 AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EeContributionsPT2',
CAST(s.Ee_Contributions_Pt2 AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Ee_Contributions_Pt2 AS FLOAT) AS 'EeContributionsPT2 Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Ee_Contributions_Pt2 AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Ee_Contributions_Pt2 AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT --Different
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Er_Contributions AS FLOAT) AS 'Star ErContributions',
CAST(pr.Er_Contributions AS FLOAT) AS 'PR ErContributions',
CAST(s.Er_Contributions AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Er_Contributions AS FLOAT) AS 'ErContributions Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Er_Contributions AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Er_Contributions AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Ee_Rebate AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EeRebate',
CAST(pr.Ee_Rebate AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EeRebate',
CAST(s.Ee_Rebate AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Ee_Rebate AS FLOAT) AS 'EeRebate Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Ee_Rebate AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Ee_Rebate AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Er_Rebate AS FLOAT) AS 'Star ErRebate',
CAST(pr.Er_Rebate AS FLOAT) AS 'PR ErRebate',
CAST(s.Er_Rebate AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Er_Rebate AS FLOAT) AS 'ErRebate Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Er_Rebate AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Er_Rebate AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.Ee_Reduction AS FLOAT) AS 'Star EeReduction',
CAST(pr.Ee_Reduction AS FLOAT) AS 'PR EeReduction',
CAST(s.Ee_Reduction AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Ee_Reduction AS FLOAT) AS 'EeReduction Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Ee_Reduction AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Ee_Reduction AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.TaxPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'Star TaxPreviousEmt',
CAST(pr.TaxPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'PR TaxPreviousEmt',
CAST(s.TaxPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.TaxPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'TaxPreviousEmt Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.TaxPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.TaxPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.TaxablePayPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'Star TaxablePayPreviousEmt',
CAST(pr.TaxablePayPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'PR TaxablePayPreviousEmt',
CAST(s.TaxablePayPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.TaxablePayPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'TaxablePayPreviousEmt Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.TaxablePayPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.TaxablePayPreviousEmt AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.TaxThisEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'Star TaxThisEmt',
CAST(pr.TaxThisEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'PR TaxThisEmt',
CAST(s.TaxThisEmt AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.TaxThisEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'TaxThisEmt Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.TaxThisEmt AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.TaxThisEmt AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.TaxablePayThisEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'Star TaxablePayThisEmt',
CAST(pr.TaxablePayThisEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'PR TaxablePayThisEmt',
CAST(s.TaxablePayThisEmt AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.TaxablePayThisEmt AS FLOAT) AS 'TaxablePayThisEmt Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.TaxablePayThisEmt AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.TaxablePayThisEmt AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.AccYearBal AS FLOAT) AS 'Star AccYearBal',
CAST(pr.AccYearBal AS FLOAT) AS 'PR AccYearBal',
CAST(s.AccYearBal AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.AccYearBal AS FLOAT) AS 'AccYearBal Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.AccYearBal AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.AccYearBal AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.PAYEYearBal AS FLOAT) AS 'Star PAYEYearBal',
CAST(pr.PAYEYearBal AS FLOAT) AS 'PR PAYEYearBal',
CAST(s.PAYEYearBal AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.PAYEYearBal AS FLOAT) AS 'PAYEYearBal Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.PAYEYearBal AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.PAYEYearBal AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.ACCYearUnits AS FLOAT) AS 'Star ACCYearUnits',
CAST(pr.ACCYearUnits AS FLOAT) AS 'PR ACCYearUnits',
CAST(s.ACCYearUnits AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.ACCYearUnits AS FLOAT) AS 'ACCYearUnits Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.ACCYearUnits AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.ACCYearUnits AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
s.EEid,
CAST(s.PAYEYearUnits AS FLOAT) AS 'Star PAYEYearUnits',
CAST(pr.PAYEYearUnits AS FLOAT) AS 'PR PAYEYearUnits',
CAST(s.PAYEYearUnits AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.PAYEYearUnits AS FLOAT) AS 'PAYEYearUnits Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
INNER JOIN payRunPayHistory pr ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.PAYEYearUnits AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.PAYEYearUnits AS FLOAT) AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode
```

Here is the picture of the results. As you can see the results are all coming under the Wrong heading name.[Any recommendations are greatly appreciated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoEGs.png)

[SO here is an example of expected result. The columns with the two different values and then the difference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ87T.png)

Comment: What did you expect `UNION` do? All the aliases you write are usless unless in the first `SELECT` eg: `Star NetPay` is usless cause that column is `Star Gross`

Comment: How many columns do you expect to be in the result?

Comment: @Sami...Im no expert lol but i thought the ones with differences would come as there own columns? Obviously i was wrong, you any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to show your expected output, BTW I'm not an expert too, still learning until the last day of my life :)

Comment: @Lennart I was hoping the two columns that didn't match and the differences between those columns to appear! So if only two columns didnt match i would want them two columns and then the difference? But if there was more i would want them. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The UNION's first SELECT decides the column names.

Comment: @Mark You want to return 100 column?

Comment: @Sami I've added an example of expected result

Comment: Do `SELECT c1, null from t1 UNION select null, cx from t2...` to get separate columns.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images (or links to images.) Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your point, but here are some suggestion based on Oracle RDBMS:

- you don't have to use DISTINCT in SELECT instruction when using UNION set operator - UNION automaticaly removes any duplicates,
- final column aliases come from the firs SELECT instruction - names from second and further SELECTs are omited,
- columns must have similar data type, but not the same data type - implicit conversions are allowded (for example '2' can be automaticaly converted from string to number),
- check MINUS set operator, if you would like to produce eny differences between results of queries.

Answer (score 0):

A relation (table) consists of a header and a set of tuples. In your example query, you are putting all of your CAST columns under the same header. If you want them in different columns you can add dummy columns, and use an aggregate at the outermost level to remove the dummies:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.EEid,
    CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'Star Gross',
    CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'PR Gross',
    CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'Gross Difference',
    CAST(null as FLOAT) AS 'Star NetPay',
    CAST(null as FLOAT) AS 'PR NetPay',
    CAST(null as FLOAT) AS 'NetPay Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
JOIN payRunPayHistory pr 
  ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) -- this looks dangerous 
  AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    s.EEid,
    CAST(null as FLOAT) AS ...,
    CAST(null as FLOAT) AS ...,
    CAST(null as FLOAT) AS ..., 
    CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'Star NetPay',
    CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'PR NetPay',
    CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'NetPay Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
JOIN payRunPayHistory pr 
    ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) != CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) 
  AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode
```

Some remarks:

- DISTINCT is redundant if you use UNION
- Comparing floats may get you into trouble
- <> is standard operator though != works in most DBMS

It however, looks as if you are using the same tables to join against, so I think you can simplify your query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.EEid,
    CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'Star Gross',
    CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'PR Gross',
    CAST(s.Gross AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.Gross AS FLOAT) AS 'Gross Difference',
    CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'Star NetPay',
    CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'PR NetPay',
    CAST(s.NetPay AS FLOAT) - CAST(pr.NetPay AS FLOAT) AS 'NetPay Difference'
FROM starPayHistory s
JOIN payRunPayHistory pr 
  ON pr.EEid = s.EEid
WHERE (s.Gross <> pr.Gross OR s.NetPay <> pr.NetPay)
  AND s.PayCode = pr.PayCode
```

I'm not clear on what you want to do where values equal, so I'll leave that part. You'll, of course, have to extend the query to include additional columns.